# How to set an icon for all forms on already finished windows application in c#?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

First off, I tried making an icon myself and then converting it to am icon file by replacing the extension name to .icon. But it couldn't be read by the application.

Secondly, I have a lot of forms on my application, so I would like to set an application icon, and individual form icons all at once if it is possible. Else, I would do it the hard way, configuring the form properties for icon.

Answer (score 0):

In first time, rename the icon extension is an error..

The content type of icon is different from png, jpg and other 
(image/vnd.microsoft.icon instead image/png, image/jpeg, etc)

You can make a custom icon (with .ico extension) with [GreenFish Icon Editor Pro](http://www.freewarefiles.com/Greenfish-Icon-Editor-Pro_program_37937.html)

It's free and easy

In second time, you can make a custom base Form class, like this:

```
public class MyProjectBaseForm : Form
{
    protected MyProjectBaseForm()
    {
        // set icon (and more property) value here
    }
}
```

and simply implement in all Form.cs (and Form.Designer.cs)

After, this work can be update easly and quickly

Hope this help!

Comment: Where should i define the baseform?

Comment: In a .cs file, just write the code. You know the class inheritance in c#?